# Flutter: how can I prevent images from reloading on tab change in CupertinoTabScaffold?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got a Cupertino-style app in Flutter with tabs. For this, I use CupertinoTabScaffold & CupertinoTabBar. Inside each tab there is only a ListView with 10 images. When I tap on bottom navigation bar to change tab, images on a tab are reloaded, even if this tab has already been opened earlier. Is this a normal behavior? And, if not, how can I prevent images from being reloaded?

Also, I have noticed, that if I use the same images on every tab, they are not redrawn (as on the second video).

I have tried to improve it using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin and increasing cacheExtent in ListView, but nothing helped.

[Example behavior with 10 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3eZr.gif)

[Example behavior with 2 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRLPI.gif)

Source code:

```
import 'package:example/bible_page.dart';
import 'package:example/expandable_page_view.dart';
import 'package:example/favorites_page.dart';
import 'package:example/home_page.dart';
import 'package:example/verses_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: TabBarPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TabBarPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TabBarPageState createState() => _TabBarPageState();
}

class _TabBarPageState extends State<TabBarPage> {
  int _currentTabIndex = 0;
  late CupertinoTabController tabController =
      CupertinoTabController(initialIndex: _currentTabIndex);
  List<Widget> _tabs = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setTabs();
  }

  void _setTabs() {
    _tabs = [Page1(), Page2(), Page3(), Page4()];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      controller: tabController,
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (context) {
            return _tabs[index];
          },
        );
      },
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        onTap: (index) {
          tabController.index = index;
        },
        backgroundColor:
            Theme.of(context).bottomNavigationBarTheme.backgroundColor,
        activeColor: Colors.purple,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Theme.of(context)
                  .bottomNavigationBarTheme
                  .unselectedItemColor,
            ),
            label: 'Page 1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.book),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.book,
              color: Theme.of(context)
                  .bottomNavigationBarTheme
                  .unselectedItemColor,
            ),
            label: 'Page 2',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.snowboarding),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.snowboarding,
              color: Theme.of(context)
                  .bottomNavigationBarTheme
                  .unselectedItemColor,
            ),
            label: 'Page 3',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.local_activity),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.local_activity,
              color: Theme.of(context)
                  .bottomNavigationBarTheme
                  .unselectedItemColor,
            ),
            label: 'Page 4',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                width: 100,
                child: Image.asset('assets/verses_images/${index + 1}.jpg'));
          }),
    ));
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}


import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Page2State createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                width: 100,
                child: Image.asset('assets/verses_images/${index + 1}.jpg'));
          }),
    ));
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}


import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Page3 extends StatefulWidget {
  Page3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Page3State createState() => _Page3State();
}

class _Page3State extends State<Page3> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                width: 100,
                child: Image.asset('assets/verses_images/${index + 1}.jpg'));
          }),
    ));
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}


import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Page4 extends StatefulWidget {
  Page4({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Page4State createState() => _Page4State();
}

class _Page4State extends State<Page4> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                width: 100,
                child: Image.asset('assets/verses_images/${index + 1}.jpg'));
          }),
    ));
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: It is because you are using a ListView.builder which build the entire list again whenever you visit to the page, if it has similar items then list will be created fast else it will take some time to render result.

Comment: @Diwyansh so, what should I use to make my list not re-render? I have a scrollable horizontal list of content, so using ListView.builder seems like the best option. Using SingleChildScrollView with Row doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I'll prefer you to use ListView.builder if your list is dynamic but if it is fixed length the you can also try ListView widget.